# Finding exact word in description column of DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, findall, exact-match

My list contains some words like : [`‘orange’, ‘cool’, ‘app’....]` and I want to output all these exact whole words (if available) from a description column in a DataFrame.

I have also attached a sample picture with code. I used `str.findall()` The picture shows, it extracts `add` from `additional`, `app` from `apple`. However, I do not want that. It should only output if it matches the whole word.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the code using

```
df['exactmatch'] = df['text'].str.findall(fr"\b({'|'.join(list1)})\b").str.join(", ")
```

Or, if there can be special chars in your `list1` words,

```
df['exactmatch'] = df['text'].str.findall(fr"(?<!\w)({'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})(?!\w)").str.join(", ")
```

The pattern created by `fr"\b({'|'.join(list1)})\b"` and `fr"(?<!\w)({'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})(?!\w)"` will look like

```
\b(orange|cool|app)\b
(?<!\w)(orange|cool|app)(?!\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjhNfi/1). Note `.str.join(", ")` is considered faster than `.apply(", ".join)`.

Comment: Thank you! However, if my text also has word with hyphen, for e.g. additional-material, or plural  e.g. apples, how can I modify my search instead of having “additional-material and apples” in my list1 but still get the output additional material and apple. Thanks!

Comment: @ShrestR Try `r"(?<!\w)(" + '|'.join([re.escape(x).replace('\\ ', r'[\s-]') for x in list1]) + r")"`

Comment: Hi, how to do the same exact match operation in pyspark df?   below is for pandas:                                                                                  df['exactmatch'] = df['text'].str.findall(fr"(?<!\w)({'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})(?!\w)").str.join(", ")

Comment: @ShrestR I do not know pyspark well, I think you should use a `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace` like `regexp_replace(col, fr"(?s)(?<!\w)({'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})(?!\w)|.?", r"\1, ")` and this value should be also replaced with `regexp_replace(<the-result-of the previous substitution>, '^(?:, )+|(?:, )+$|(, )+', r'\1')`